# Prompt Error with local GPTQ LLM and langchain

Tags: huggingface-transformers, langchain, large-language-model

I'm receiving the following error:

ValueError: Argument `prompt` is expected to be a string. Instead found <class 'list'>. If you want to run the LLM on multiple prompts, use `generate` instead.

Note - when I utilize model = ChatOpenAI() ## I do not get the Error.

### Load LLM

def get_llm_model():

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_ID, use_fast=True)
model = AutoGPTQForCausalLM.from_quantized(
    "TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GPTQ",

    use_safetensors=True,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    device="cuda:0",
    use_triton=False,
    quantize_config=None,
)
generation_config = GenerationConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL_ID)
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_length=2048,
    temperature=0,
    top_p=0.95,
    repetition_penalty=1.15,
    generation_config=generation_config,
)
local_llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)
return local_llm
```

### Determine Topic of the Question being asked.

def determine_topic(question):

```
model = get_llm_model()
template = f"Determine the topic in the following question: \n{question}. 
human_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)
chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([human_prompt])
result = model(chat_prompt.format_prompt(question=question).to_messages())
return result.content
```

question = "How do you know x about topic y"

determine_topic(question)

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`ChatOpenAI` implements `BaseChatModel` and your `local_llm` not. You can try with `OpenAI` (`from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI`) which also implements `BaseLLM` and not `BaseChatModel` instead of `ChatOpenAI` (`from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI`) and you will see the same error appear.

It's just a matter of different interfaces. Either you change your logic to fit `BaseChatModel` or make sure you provide an implementation of `BaseChatModel`.

Some useful references:

- https://blog.langchain.dev/chat-models/

In your case you will get it working using

```
chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(human_prompt)
```

instead of

```
chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([human_prompt])
```